# sqlite3.OperationalError: near ",": syntax error python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I know this is a repeated question and I've looked at all of them however I cant see what I'm doing wrong.

this is my sqlite3 code:

```
cursor.execute('''DELETE FROM dates WHERE (Date, Start, End) VALUES( ? , ? , ? );''',
               (fulldaterem, starttimehour2, endtimehour2))
```

and get the error:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near ",": syntax error
```

where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `DELETE` statement doesn't take any `VALUES` section. See the [`DELETE` documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_delete.html):

> [image: DELETE grammar]

You need to build a boolean expression for your `WHERE` clause:

```
cursor.execute(
    '''DELETE FROM dates
       WHERE Date=? AND Start=? AND End=?''',
    (fulldaterem, starttimehour2, endtimehour2))
```